# How do I tell lcov where to find my .cpp & .h files?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov, lcov, unittest++

My source and build tree looks like this (see [Makefile to put object files from source files different directories into a single, separate directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102469/makefile-to-put-object-files-from-source-files-different-directories-into-a-singl)) after a make (which builds and runs FooAndBarTests):

```
src
- Foo.cpp
- Bar.cpp
inc
- Foo.h
- Bar.h
test
- FooTest.cpp
- BarTest.cpp
- Main.cpp
- Makefile
- obj
  - Foo.gcda
  - Foo.gcno
  - Bar.gcda
  - Bar.gcno
- FooAndBarTests
UnitTest++
- libUnitTest++.a
- src
  - ...
```

I can then produce .gcov  files in the test directory by running `gcov -o obj/ ../src/Foo.cpp` and `gcov -o obj/ ../src/Bar.cpp`.

But if I run `lcov -d obj/ -c -o FooAndBarTests.lcov` I get:

```
Capturing coverage data from obj/
Found gcov version: 4.2.1
Scanning obj/ for .gcda files ...
Found 4 data files in obj/
Processing Foo.gcda
../src/Foo.cpp:cannot open source file
Processing FooTest.gcda
FooTest.cpp:cannot open source file
../inc/Foo.h:cannot open source file
../UnitTest++/src/Checks.h:cannot open source file
...
```

And then when I run `genhtml FooAndBarTests.lcov` I get:

```
Reading data file FooAndBarTests.lcov
Found 45 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/Users/dspitzer/FooAndBar/test"
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file UnitTest++/src/Checks.h
genhtml: ERROR: cannot open /Users/dspitzer/FooAndBar/test/UnitTest++/src/Checks.h for reading!
```

How do I tell lcov and genhtml where the .cpp and .h files are?

Comment: I don't know for sure but try using the -g option when compiling. It adds meta data for debugging purposes (including file paths and line numbers, I think).

Comment: I am already using the -g option when compiling.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `-b` option to `lcov`. The `-b` option specifies code base.

Comment: Adding "-b ." to my lcov command-line (when run in the same directory where I did the make) did the trick.