# Coverage report when source and objects are in different directories

Tags: code-coverage, lcov

I am trying to generate coverage report for my project and running into a problem.

I understand that to get the coverage info, I need .gcno, .gcda and source files. 
My current project dir structure is

```
/root/proj/src   --> top level Makefile and main.c
    /root/proj/src/module1
    /root/proj/src/module2
    .....                  -> contains all .c/.h ,makefile  
/root/proj/build/obj -> contains  all .o,.gcno,.gcda files after compilation 
/root/proj/build/exe  -> contains the executable
```

(copying minimal lines below to show the problem)

```
cd /root/proj/build/obj
```

when I run

```
lcov -b ../../src/ --directory . --capture --output-file app.info
Processing module1.gcda
module1.c:cannot open source file

...... 

Finished .info-file creation
```

Then :

```
genhtml --legend   -o ./latest_code_cov/ app.info
Reading data file app.info
Found 5 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/root/proj/src"
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file src/module1.c
genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /root/proj/src/module1.c
bash-4.1$
```

1) Do I need to change my makefile to dump `.gcno/.gcda` files in the same folders as the source?

2) Is there a way(some flag) to set the source file path in `.gcno/.gcda` files?

Any suggestions?

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)

lcov: LCOV version 1.13

Comment: Is this the same issue reported here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4412709/671509