# substituting folder path in $(SOURCES) of a makefile

Tags: makefile

I am looking for a way to substitute the folder on a list of source files variable within makefile.

Is there something that works here?

I start off by finding my source files

```
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard  $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
```

the results (if I understand GNU makefiles correctly) look typically like

> src/main.cpp
>   src/sensor.cpp

then I build by object files

```
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.opp}
```

this replaces the extensions of my source files as per expected.

Finally, I want to replace "src/" with "obj/"

```
program_C_OBJPATH := ${subst $(SRCDIR) , $(OBJDIR) , $(program_C_OBJS)}
program_CXX_OBJPATH := ${subst $(SRCDIR) , $(OBJDIR) , $(program_CXX_OBJS)}
```

However, this does not work.

I have gone through the GNU makefile website to no avail. This solution [Makefile to put object files from source files different directories into a single, separate directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102469/makefile-to-put-object-files-from-source-files-different-directories-into-a-sing) comes close but the objects directory must be explicitly included everywhere and the sources directory does not include source path information.

In my makefile the list of source files include the path and I would prefer that the list of object files include the corresponding object directory, too.

The rest of the makefile tries also to use variables

linking stage

```
$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(program_OBJS) -o "$(program_NAME)"
```

compile stage

```
%.opp : %.cpp | mkdirobjdir
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o "$@" "$<"
```

and finally the rules

```
main_enose.opp : main_enose.cpp core_enose.cpp core_enose.h
$(OBJDIR)/core_enose.opp : core_enose.cpp core_enose.h
$(OBJDIR)/core_enose.h :
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem here is the spaces around the commas in the `$(subst)` calls. make isn't ignoring them the way you expect it might. It is seeing them as literal values in the string to find, the string to replace and the to do the replacement in.

Remove them.

```
program_C_OBJPATH := ${subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(program_C_OBJS)}
program_CXX_OBJPATH := ${subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(program_CXX_OBJS)}
```

That said you probably either want to use [`$(patsubst)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-patsubst-1) to limit where the replacement happens:

```
program_C_OBJPATH := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(program_C_OBJS))
program_CXX_OBJPATH := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(program_CXX_OBJS))
```

or you want to use [`$(notdir)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-notdir) and [`$(addprefix)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-addprefix) to handle stripping all the directory information and adding it back:

```
program_C_OBJPATH := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(program_C_OBJS)))
program_CXX_OBJPATH := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(program_CXX_OBJS)))
```

Comment: thanks! This works correctly. It doesn't seem to solve my problem later on though. What happens is that the following rule does not work .    `$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)` . It says `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj_dbg/core_enose.opp', needed by 'program'.  Stop.` It seems the linking rule is the one that fails

Comment: Where do you define the rule for `obj_dbg/core_enose.opp`? You didn't show that part of your makefile.

Comment: indeed, please have a look now. I realise the rules cannot be without path now, so I prefixed them as follows: `$(OBJDIR)/core_enose.opp : $(SRCDIR)/core_enose.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core_enose.h` . But this fails as well.

Comment: ok adding `$(OBJDIR)/%.opp : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp` finally succeeds. But I do not understand why. I mean the "%" in "%.opp" should include all the path+filename (without extension). Also I now have to include $(objdir) and $(srcdir) in all my rules. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: `%.o: %.c` does have `%` match any path components but it needs them to be the **same** components on both sides which your case doesn't have. Editing the question here was likely the wrong thing to do (as the question here was asked and answered). I'm happy to help with your other questions but you should ask them all as a new question (link it in a comment here if you want so I'll be sure to see it).

Comment: Indeed better a new Q to tackle it. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214155/gnu-makefiles-no-targets-are-built-when-setting-up-the-makefile-in-a-certain-wa