# How to compile files that reside in different directory in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have seen this questions asked before but was not able to decipher those answers.

Lets say I reside in working directory, lets call it proj and this proj directory contains src folder which contains all the *.cpp files. I want to compile those file staying on the proj directory because in future I will be creating bin directory and placing the *.o and binary in bin.

So my proj directory currently contains : Makefile and src

What I have done so far is :

```
SOURCE = src

# This gives the path to the proj directory
CURRENT_DIR = $(shell pwd) 

# This gives list of all the *.cpp files
SRC = $(shell cd $(SOURCE) && echo *.cpp)

# Here all the name of the files stored in SRC are converted from *.cpp to *.o
OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGE)

# use the content of SRC to compile
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(info $(OBJS))

$(OBJS): $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $?
```

When I try to run the make command it says

make: *** No rule to make target 'xxx.cpp', needed by 'xxx.o'. Stop

Now I know what it is trying to say. It gives error because although it knows the name of the file, since the file is not in the current directory makefile does not know about src folder and hence have no clue about the *.cpp files.

So my question is:  Is there any macros or trick to use in makefile to make sure makefile see the xxx.cpp in src folder while staying in the current directory( I don't want to specify the folder by hand here)?

Comment: Can you describe what you don't understand about, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4102619/939557 (which was the first question shown under the "Related" links to the right)?  Because I would give basically that same answer, so if you're not understanding it we'll need to dig deeper.

Comment: I should point out in answer to your last question, that there is no way to have the makefile see files in the `src` folder without telling it to look there in _SOME_ way.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say you _don't want to specify the folder by hand_, but the directory name must appear somewhere in your makefile.  There's no way to tell make it should just go wandering around the filesystem looking for files in some directory somewhere with the names you've provided.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes you are right .. after looking into it I came to know about addprefix and that solved my problem. Its was just about appending a string $SOURCE to the $SRC : $(addprefix $(SOURCE), $(SRC))